# Manipulation with strings: Capitalize every word after any delimiter in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am trying to manipulate string so it capitalizes each word after any delimiter. 
Currently, I am using `capwords()` method imported from `string` module. Code sample:

```
my_string = "hello MY-naMe-is john"
new_string = string.capwords(my_string)
print(new_string)
```

Using only `capwords()` method, result is this:

> Hello My-name-is John

Result that I am trying to get:

> Hello My-Name-Is John

Is it possible to use more than one separator in `capwords()`? Is there a solution to this while still using `capwords()` method? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use title() in built method

```
my_string = "hello MY-naMe-is john"
new_string = my_string.title()
print(new_string)

#'Hello My-Name-Is John'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use `capwords` and get the result that you need. The `capwords(s, sep=None)` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.capwords) shows the steps that it undergoes:

1. `str.split()` - here the `sep` is used (if provided)
2. `str.capitalize()` - first character of each item in the list (from `split`) is capitalized
3. `str.join()` - the string is joined back

`split` takes just one `sep`. However, `re.split` takes multiple delimeters/separators.

Use `title()` if you want to achieve your desired result, as suggested by @Ananth.P